# Search Form for Pods Framework Tutorial

Tags: php, wordpress, search, podscms

I’m stuck! I’m a beginner at using PHP. It’s been weeks and I can’t, for the life of me, get a search form to work with my pods! I’ve been reading through the forums and codex for weeks but I’m so confused.

I have a pod named Books. This pod have custom fields of Author, Year, Genre. I want to create a search form that can search through the custom fields that I want via a tick box, and have the results displayed using a pods template I made. I also want to be able to sort the results with any of my custom fields.

Are there any noob friendly tutorials that can guide me through making this?
I would extremely appreciate any help or advice that could point me in the right direction.
I’M DESPERATE!!!
- Angelica

Answer (score 0):

This was probably related to this issue: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-not-working-33?replies=9

You had an .htaccess block which was redirecting URLs with query strings, stripping off the query strings:

```
# Remove Extra Query Parameters
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.*
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=.*
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping me!!!!!!!!!!!!!

One more thing regarding search form for pods.
The following code should display a dropdown menu containing my custom fields right beside the search form , right?


`echo $pod->filters( array(
 'fields' => array( 'book_title', 'book_author', 'book_genre' )
) );`


However nothing is appearing except for the text box and search button.

Comment: Answered your question on the wordpress.org forums, filters only supports relationship filters right now.